# PostgreSQL insert or update trigger function volatility category

Tags: postgresql, immutability, volatile, volatility

Assume, i have 2 tables in my DB (postgresql-9.x)

```
CREATE TABLE FOLDER (
    KEY BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    PATH TEXT,
    NAME TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE FOLDERFILE (
    FILEID BIGINT,
    PATH TEXT,
    PATHKEY BIGINT
);
```

I automatically update `FOLDERFILE.PATHKEY` from `FOLDER.KEY` whenever i insert into or update `FOLDERFILE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION folderfile_fill_pathkey() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  pathkey bigint;
  changed boolean;
BEGIN
  IF tg_op = 'INSERT' THEN
     changed := TRUE;
    ELSE IF old.FILEID != new.FILEID THEN
       changed := TRUE;
    END IF;
  END IF;
  IF changed THEN
     SELECT INTO pathkey key FROM FOLDER WHERE PATH = new.path;
     IF FOUND THEN
       new.pathkey = pathkey;
     ELSE
       new.pathkey = NULL;
     END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN new;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER folderfile_fill_pathkey_trigger AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON FOLDERFILE FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fcliplink_fill_pathkey();
```

So the question is about function `folderfile_fill_pathkey()` volatility. Documentations says

> Any function with side-effects must be labeled VOLATILE

But as far as i understand – this function does not change any data in the tables it rely on, so i can mark this function as `IMMUTABLE`. It that correct?

Would there be any problem with IMMUTABLE trigger function if I bulk-insert many rows into `FOLDERFILE` within the same transaction, like:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO FOLDERFILE ( ... );
...
INSERT INTO FOLDERFILE ( ... );
COMMIT;
```

Comment: This *"function"* (strictly speaking, its body) is not `IMMUTABLE`, it's just `STABLE` (it selects from your `FOLDER` table, which can change over time: your function does not guarantee the same results for the same *"parameters"*) -- **but**, it's a trigger, not a classical function: function volatility only matters for query optimizations, but it will only cause you troubles, if you optimize triggers, [f.ex. `STABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) - *It is inappropriate for `AFTER` triggers that wish to query rows modified by the current command.*

Comment: Thanks @pozs! I did not actually fully understood the difference between `IMMUTABLE` and `STABLE`, so I'll have to fix few things now in my DB. So your comment is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @pozs, so as far as i got it – making my function `STABLE` instead of `VOLATILE` will not give me any performance advantages? Would be nice also if you make it an answer so i can accept it – otherwise i'll have to do it myself.

Comment: it's hard to predict, if `STABLE` actually perform better, or not. Query optimization depends on a lot of things. (In your case -- i.e. you do not query the trigger's target table `FOLDERFILE` inside the function -- it should not matter). But, if you want to be precise, you should test both variants with real data.

Comment: ok, thanks, i'll do benchmark later and post result here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, as @pozs already pointed out, the function definition you have provided is most definitely `STABLE` rather than `IMMUTABLE` since it performs database look-ups. This means that the result is not simply derived from the input parameters (as `IMMUTABLE` would suggest), but also from the data stored in your `FOLDER` table (which is bound to change). As per the documentation:

> `STABLE` indicates that the function cannot modify the database, and
>   that within a single table scan it will consistently return the same
>   result for the same argument values, but that its result could change
>   across SQL statements. **This is the appropriate selection for functions**
>   **whose results depend on database lookups**, parameter variables (such as
>   the current time zone), etc.

Secondly, adding stability modifiers (`IMMUTABLE`/`STABLE`/`VOLATILE`) to your trigger functions serves an illustrative purpose at best, since AFAIK PostgreSQL doesn't actually perform any planning that would warrant their use. The [following post](http://postgresql.nabble.com/Triggers-with-DO-functionality-td5492468.html) from the `pgsql-hackers` mailing list seems to support my claim:

> Volatility is a complete no-op for a trigger function anyway, as are
>   other planner parameters such as cost/rows, because there is no
>   planning involved in trigger calls.

To sum up: you're probably better off avoiding the stability keywords in your trigger(!) procedures for now, since including them seems to add little to no benefit but entails several unexpected caveats/pitfalls (see the end of @pozs's first comment).